# Calculating the intensity of a FFT peak

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, fft

for the physical laboratory our professor gave us a task to make analysis of a frequency spectrum of a plucked string. After the sound acquisition we were given a script to perform a FFT.

[After the FFT we now have several frequency peaks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9qUz.png)

He then told us that we have to calculate the intensity of each peak separately. I am new to this topic, so I am asking for your help how to alter the given code to get as an output peak intensity let's say from 760 to 765 Hz.

The code is here:

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft,ifft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import blackman

data =  np.loadtxt("mic.txt")
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

fy = fft(y)

print np.sum(y),"==",fy[0]

n = len(x)
t = x[-1]
fx = np.linspace(0,n/t,n)

plt.plot(fx[0:n/2],np.abs(fy[0:n/2]))

plt.xlabel("frequency (Hz)")
plt.show()
```

I would appreciate your help, Matthew

Comment: your input mic signal wobbles up and down over time ... plot this to see this curve ... its in the time domain where the left right axis is time and up down is amplitude of the pluck ... this array sent into your fft call returns as a new array where each element of the array is a different frequency ... the value of each array element typically is a complex number from which you can calculate the magnitude of the frequency for the array element ... I suggest you tease apart the code so this becomes evident ... especially iterate across this fft array and zoom in on elements around 760 Hz

Answer (score 0):

By peak intensity I assume you mean the magnitude of each peak (of course it can be normalized). I used [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) to get the peaks in the spectrum. Because FFT returns complex values, I used it on the absolute value of y. This is a generic example, so finding the maximums is not that trivial in most cases. There are other peak detection tools, such as [`scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt.html), or [`peakutils`](https://pypi.org/project/PeakUtils/) package.
From the [scipy tutorials](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html#d-discrete-fourier-transforms) here is a minimal working example:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.signal import find_peaks

N = 600
T = 1.0 / 800.0
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0 * np.pi * x) + 0.5 * np.sin(80.0 * 2.0 * np.pi * x)

yf = fft(y)
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0 / (2.0 * T), N//2)

# finding the peaks in the absolute value of y
y_abs = 2.0 / N * np.abs(yf[0:N//2])
peakind, _ = find_peaks(y_abs)

plt.plot(xf, y_abs)

# plotting the peaks
plt.plot(xf[peakind], y_abs[peakind], 'k.')

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The magnitue of the peaks is just

```py
>>> y_abs[peakind]
[0.70947072 0.4914645 ]
```